# How to pass a variable from a controller to a view after posting some data in the function in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

```
//Error

Undefined variable $size
```

```
//Controller

public function pos_F(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->filter;
    return view('facfilter')->with('name', $name);
}
```

```
//View

<h1>{{$name}}</h1>
```

**This is happening after posting the data and then if I am trying to pass any variable it gives an error and if I have to do `{{session('size')` with `return back()->with(['size' => $size, 'name' => $name])` it still gives the error of null variable passed in view.**
**Any Help would be really appreciated, Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

You are passing variable to view by Flash Session.

**Data stored in the flash session will be available immediately and during the subsequent HTTP request. After the subsequent HTTP request, the flashed data will be deleted.**

if you have scenario in which you must have to pass data to view with session, then first check if session is present or not.

```
@if (session('size'))
     {{ session('size') }}
@endif
```

above code will prevent code screen error.